# toggle div depending on which one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

```
 var header = $("#accordion");

            $.each(data, function () {
                header.append("<a id='Headanchor' href='javascript:toggleDiv($(this));'>" +   this.LongName + "</a>" + "<br />",
                "<div id='myContent' style='display:none'>" +
                "<ul>" +
                "<li>" + "ID: " + this.Id + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + "Short Name: " + this.ShortName + "</li>" +  "</ul>" + "</div>"
                );


                function toggleDiv(element) {
       var x = element.next();
       x.toggle();

       <div id="accordion">

</div>
```

working script for just one div i.e. first

```
function toggleDiv() {

              $("#myContent").toggle();

}
```

I want to toggle the div's depending on which anchor tag is clicked but not able to do it. If i use the id selector then the first div  gets toggled but not rest of them as they get the same id's which is erong..can somone please help me out with this ....

Comment: Try closing your script tag before resuming html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `javascript:toggleDiv($(this))` `this` is pointing to window, not to an object. See [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fGTgM/1/). So change code below:

```
"<a id='Headanchor' href='javascript:toggleDiv($(this));'>"
```

to:

```
"<a id='Headanchor' href='#' onclick='return toggleDiv($(this));'>"
```

and JS code:

```
function toggleDiv(element) {
       var x = element.next();
       x.toggle();
       return false;
}
```

Besides, IDs should be unique and in your code you will have multiple Headanchor elements.

Comment: yep this works thanks a lot..I have removed the id's ..I was just trying different odd's :) anyways thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Hide all, and only show the one you want approach:

```
$('#accordian>div').hide()      // hide all divs within the accordian
  .find('#selectedId').show();  // then show the one that matches the ID you want
```

But save yourself the trouble of re-inventing the wheel and use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com).